# Horizontal Pager with Paging3 in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist, android-jetpack-compose-pager

There are two screens in my app. The first screen shows the list of images on the device by using the `Paging3` library in a vertical grid. Now, when the user clicks on an image, I am passing the click position to the second screen where I am using `HorizontalPager` from Accompanist to show the images in full screen. Both the screens share the same ViewModel to fetch images using `Paging3`.

The code to show the images in HorizontalPager is shown below.

```kotlin
val images: LazyPagingItems<MediaStoreImage> =
    viewModel.getImages(initialLoadSize = args.currentImagePosition + 1, pageSize = 50)
        .collectAsLazyPagingItems()

val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = currentImagePosition)

Box(modifier = modifier) {
    HorizontalPager(
        count = images.itemCount,
        state = pagerState,
        itemSpacing = 16.dp
    ) { page ->
        ZoomableImage(
            modifier = modifier,
            imageUri = images[page]?.contentUri
        )
    }
}
```

Here, `currentImagePosition` is the index of the image clicked on the first screen. I am setting the `initialLoadSize` to `currentImagePosition + 1` which makes sure that the clicked image to be shown is already fetched by the paging library.

When the second screen is opened, the clicked image is shown in full screen as expected. However, when the user swipes for the next image, instead of loading the next image, the image with the index `50` and so on gets loaded as the user swipes further.

I am not sure what am I missing here. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit: Added ViewModel, Repository & Paging code**

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
fun getImages(initialLoadSize: Int = 50): Flow<PagingData<MediaStoreImage>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 50,
                initialLoadSize = initialLoadSize,
                enablePlaceholders = true
            )
        ) {
            repository.getImagesPagingSource()
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

**Repository**

```kotlin
fun getImagesPagingSource(): PagingSource<Int, MediaStoreImage> {
        return ImagesDataSource { limit, offset ->
            getSinglePageImages(
                limit,
                offset
            )
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
private fun getSinglePageImages(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<MediaStoreImage> {
        val images = ArrayList<MediaStoreImage>()
        val cursor = getCursor(limit, offset)

        cursor?.use {
            val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val dateModifiedColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)
            val displayNameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val sizeColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE)

            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
                val dateModified =
                    Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(it.getLong(dateModifiedColumn)))
                val dateModifiedString = getFormattedDate(dateModified)
                val displayName = it.getString(displayNameColumn)
                val size = it.getLong(sizeColumn)
                val sizeInMbKb = getFileSize(size)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    id
                )

                images.add(
                    MediaStoreImage(
                        id,
                        displayName,
                        dateModifiedString,
                        contentUri,
                        sizeInMbKb
                    )
                )
            }
        }

        cursor?.close()
        return images
    }
```

```kotlin
private fun getCursor(limit: Int, offset: Int): Cursor? {
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE
        )

        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val bundle = bundleOf(
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SELECTION to "${MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH} like ? ",
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SELECTION_ARGS to arrayOf("%${context.getString(R.string.app_name)}%"),
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_OFFSET to offset,
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT to limit,
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SORT_COLUMNS to arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED),
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SORT_DIRECTION to ContentResolver.QUERY_SORT_DIRECTION_DESCENDING
            )

            context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                bundle,
                null
            )
        } else {
            context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA} like ? ",
                arrayOf("%${context.getString(R.string.app_name)}%"),
                "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED} DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset",
                null
            )
        }
    }
```

**Paging Data Source**

```kotlin
class ImagesDataSource(private val onFetch: (limit: Int, offset: Int) -> List<MediaStoreImage>) :
    PagingSource<Int, MediaStoreImage>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, MediaStoreImage>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let {
            state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, MediaStoreImage> {
        val pageNumber = params.key ?: 0
        val pageSize = params.loadSize
        val images = onFetch.invoke(pageSize, pageNumber * pageSize)
        val prevKey = if (pageNumber > 0) pageNumber.minus(1) else null
        val nextKey = if (images.isNotEmpty()) pageNumber.plus(1) else null

        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = images,
            prevKey = prevKey,
            nextKey = nextKey
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `viewModel.getImage` instead of `viewModel.getImages`? I'm not very good at android so I'm not sure

Comment: Maybe `pageSize = 50` made it go to index 50?

Comment: The code you posted looks ok, important is the implementation of `viewModel.getImages` which you did not provide. One thing though, you say that both screens share ViewModel - why would you load the data again on the second screen? You can just have them cached in that ViewModel and reuse them.

Comment: This might be the problem `initialLoadSize: Int = 50`

Comment: @DialFrost I don't think `initialLoadSize` is the problem. The same code works perfectly with `LazyVerticalGrid` on the first screen.

Comment: are you sure, that in your load method at ImagesDataSource `val images = onFetch.invoke(pageSize, pageNumber * pageSize)` ? Maybe `...invoke(pageSize, pageNumber)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. Whenever the second screen was opened, the `getImages()` function of the shared ViewModel was called which created a new instance of Pager. This new instance of the Pager was different from the one used on the first screen. Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71413278/5095473) answer on StackOverflow, I created the Pager in the `init` block of the ViewModel as shown below.

```kotlin
    val images: Flow<PagingData<MediaStoreImage>>

    init {
        images = Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 50,
                initialLoadSize = 50,
                enablePlaceholders = true
            )
        ) {
            repository.getImagesPagingSource()
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

On the second screen, I collected the paging items as shown below.

```kotlin
val lazyImages: LazyPagingItems<MediaStoreImage> = viewModel.images.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```

Now, I didn't have to pass the `initialLoadSize` as the Pager created in the first screen was being reused which had already loaded the items.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in the Paging3 library. Consider sharing the codebase with the issue tracker team to help with the resolution of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243563681.